# Split CSV Column by pipe character and count unique values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file that has columns of pipe delimited values. Example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple|Bear |
| 2 | Apple |Car |
| 3 | Dog|Cat|Emu |
| 4 | Bear|Emu |

For column B, I need to split it by the pipe and count each unique value.
The output would look like this:

| B | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Bear | 2 |
| Emu | 2 |
| Car | 1 |
| Cat | 1 |
| Dog | 1 |

I'm trying to learn D3.js and I'm not all that experienced with d3 or javascript yet. So, right now, I have the following:

```
var b_counts = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.B })
        .rollup(function(item) {
            return item.length;
        })
        .entries(data)
        .map(function(group) {
            return {
                B: group.key,
                Count: group.value
            }
        });
```

Which works really well to give me the count of each unique item in the column B:

| B | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Apple|Bear | 1 |
| Apple |Car | 1 |
| Dog|Cat|Emu | 1 |
| Bear|Emu | 1 |

But what I really want is the count of each unique value in B.

In python with pandas, I would just do

```
df.B.split("|").explode().value_counts().rename_axis("B").reset_index(name="Count")
```

But javascript/d3 are, again, foreign to me and google hasn't exactly given me solutions I can piece together to make it do what I need.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this. First we get an array containing all individual values in the B column. Then we use [d3.rollup](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/README.md#rollup) to count the number of times each value appears.

```
const data = [
  { A: 1, B: 'Apple|Bear' },
  { A: 2, B: 'Apple|Car' },
  { A: 3, B: 'Dog|Cat|Emu' },
  { A: 4, B: 'Bear|Emu' },
];

// split each B attribute by the pipe
// flatten the 2D array into a 1D array
const values = data.map(d => d.B.split('|')).flat();

// count the number of times each value appears
const counts = d3.rollup(
  values,
  group => group.length,
  d => d
);
```

That produces a Map. If you instead want an array of objects, then you can do

```
// count the number of times each value appears
// rollups returns an array of key-value pairs
const counts = d3.rollups(
  values,
  group => group.length,
  d => d
)
  // convert the array of arrays into an array of objects
  .map(([B, Count]) => ({B, Count}))
```

Comment: Thank you, while this didn't directly solve my problem, it helped me figure out what to do!

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to the result as an array of objects instead of as a map.